# Incrementing frequency in data,for a specific number using a Python dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset like:

```
a   
c   
c   
d   
b   
a   
a   
d   
d   
c
c   
b   
a   
b
```

I want to add a column that looks like the one below. When 'c' is reached, the new column will be zero and then be increased by one. Is there a way we can do this using python?

```
a   1
c   0
c   0
d   2
b   2
a   2
a   2
d   2
d   2
c   0
c   0
b   3
a   3
b   3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
s = df['col'].eq('c')
df['new'] = s.ne(s.shift())[~s].cumsum().reindex(df.index, fill_value=0)
```

---

```
s = df['col'].ne('c')
df['new'] = (s & ~s.shift(fill_value=False)).cumsum().where(s, 0)
```

---

```
print (df)
   col  new
0    a    1
1    c    0
2    c    0
3    d    2
4    b    2
5    a    2
6    a    2
7    d    2
8    d    2
9    c    0
10   c    0
11   b    3
12   a    3
13   b    3
```

**Explanation**:

First filter `c` (mask), get first values of consecutive groups by compare shifted values (consecutive), filter non `c` values (filtered) and create groups cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) (cumsum), last add 0 by [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) (out):

```
print (df.assign(mask = df['col'].eq('c'),
                 consecutive=s.ne(s.shift()),
                 filtered=s.ne(s.shift())[~s],
                 cumsum=s.ne(s.shift())[~s].cumsum(),
                 out=s.ne(s.shift())[~s].cumsum().reindex(df.index, fill_value=0)))

   col  new   mask  consecutive filtered  cumsum  out
0    a    1  False         True     True     1.0    1
1    c    0   True         True      NaN     NaN    0
2    c    0   True        False      NaN     NaN    0
3    d    2  False         True     True     2.0    2
4    b    2  False        False    False     2.0    2
5    a    2  False        False    False     2.0    2
6    a    2  False        False    False     2.0    2
7    d    2  False        False    False     2.0    2
8    d    2  False        False    False     2.0    2
9    c    0   True         True      NaN     NaN    0
10   c    0   True        False      NaN     NaN    0
11   b    3  False         True     True     3.0    3
12   a    3  False        False    False     3.0    3
13   b    3  False        False    False     3.0    3
```

Another idea is filter non `c`(mask), then get first Trues by no `c` group (irst_true_per_groups), add cumulative sum (cumsum) and last replace `c` rows by `0` in [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) (out):

```
print (df.assign(mask = df['col'].ne('c'),
                  first_true_per_groups=s & ~s.shift(fill_value=False),
                  cumsum=(s & ~s.shift(fill_value=False)).cumsum(),
                  out=(s & ~s.shift(fill_value=False)).cumsum().mask(s, 0)))

   col   mask  first_true_per_groups  cumsum  out
0    a   True                   True       1    0
1    c  False                  False       1    1
2    c  False                  False       1    1
3    d   True                   True       2    0
4    b   True                  False       2    0
5    a   True                  False       2    0
6    a   True                  False       2    0
7    d   True                  False       2    0
8    d   True                  False       2    0
9    c  False                  False       2    2
10   c  False                  False       2    2
11   b   True                   True       3    0
12   a   True                  False       3    0
13   b   True                  False       3    0
```

Comment: Hi jezrael,
I appreciate the response. However, if you could kindly explain the logic, that would be wonderful. Thanks!

Comment: @AkshatSrivastav - answer was edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
    df1.assign(col2=df1.col1.ne('c').astype(int))\
        .assign(col3=lambda dd:(dd.col2.diff()==1).cumsum())\
        .assign(col4=lambda dd:dd.col2*(dd.col2+dd.col3))
    
    
       col1  col2  col3  col4
    0     a     1     0     1
    1     c     0     0     0
    2     c     0     0     0
    3     d     1     1     2
    4     b     1     1     2
    5     a     1     1     2
    6     a     1     1     2
    7     d     1     1     2
    8     d     1     1     2
    9     c     0     1     0
    10    c     0     1     0
    11    b     1     2     3
    12    a     1     2     3
    13    b     1     2     3


or 

df1=df1.assign(col2=(df1.eq('c')&df1.shift().ne('c')).cumsum()+1)
df1.loc[df1.col1=='c']=0
df1
```